# Submitting a form, and getting the result using mechanise in python

Tags: python, forms, web-scraping, mechanize

I am trying to use mechanise to submit a web-form and print out the results for me. The input coordinates are being fed from a CSV file.

```
def form_scraper(xcord,ycord):
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.set_handle_refresh(False)
    br.open('http://www.whoi.edu/marine/ndsf/cgi-bin/NDSFutility.cgi?form=0&from=XY&to=LatLon')

    for form in br.forms():
        print 'Form name:', form.name

    br.select_form('XY2LLForm')

    br.form['Xcord'] = xcord
    br.form['Ycord'] = ycord

    br.form['DecLat'] = '18.10219969497151'
    br.form['DecLon'] = '79.00285162135349'

    response = br.submit()
    form_result = response.read()
    print form_result
```

This gives me the following error and produces no output.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "converter.py", line 31, in <module>
    form_scraper('1', '2')
  File "converter.py", line 20, in form_scraper
    response = br.submit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 541, in submit
    return self.open(self.click(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 255, in _mech_open
    raise response
mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `action` attribute of the form you are using specifies a location that does not exist. The form does not have a submit button. The reason the form works when you use it in your browser is that clicking the "Convert" button runs a JavaScript function which will do the actual calculation and write the results in the table at the bottom of the page.

I'm afraid you can't use mechanize to retrieve the results because it doesn't handle JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks Matthias, that's what I had figured. What tool would you suggest to handle a JavaScript form?